# How to decide batch size when using tensor flow with my own data?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, machine-learning, tensorflow

I am trying to use this (https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/examples/3_NeuralNetworks/multilayer_perceptron.py) tutorial with my own data but couldn't make it work. My data is [1X10] sized vectors. Tutorial is about MNIST data and I am trying to feed the system with different kind of vectors.

I am getting the error :

```
% (np_val.shape, subfeed_t.name, str(subfeed_t.get_shape())))
ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (0, 1) for Tensor u'Placeholder_1:0',
    which has shape '(?, 2)'
```

Error arise from batch_x and batch_y but I couldn't figure out how to decide them. I will appreciate every idea to solve this problem. Thanks

```html
    # Training cycle
    for epoch in range(training_epochs):
        avg_cost = 0.
        total_batch = int(train_data.shape[0]/batch_size)
        # Loop over all batches
        for i in range(total_batch):


            batch_x = train_data[:i*batch_size]
            batch_y = train_labels[:i*batch_size]

            np.reshape(batch_x, (-1, 10))
            np.reshape(batch_y, (-1, 1))
            # Run optimization op (backprop) and cost op (to get loss value)
            _, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={x: batch_x,
                                                          y: batch_y})
            # Compute average loss
            avg_cost += c / total_batch
        # Display logs per epoch step
        if epoch % display_step == 0:
            print("Epoch:", '%04d' % (epoch+1), "cost=", \
                "{:.9f}".format(avg_cost))
    print("Optimization Finished!")
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is probably with how your `batch_y` looks. It seems that your input placeholder `y` is expecting tensors of size `[?, 2]` (here `?` refers to variable size) but you are feeding tensors of size `[0, 1]`. While it is already strange that your first dimension of `y_batch` is 0 (I would check why that happens) there is also the problem that the second dimension of `y_batch` seems to be 1 when it is expected to be 2 - this is probably why you see that error. Why do you reshape `batch_y` before feeding it to the model (`np.reshape(batch_y, (-1, 1))`)? The model defines the input placeholders in a certain shape (for you e.g. `[?, 2]`) and you must always adhere to that shape both during training and test.